# How to dump files from a one github branch at the root level of another branch

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I'm working on a GitHub action that generate files into a folder. In this case, a `public` folder. I need to copy these generated files onto another branch. The new branch is supposed to be the deploy branch.The new branch is supposed to be the *deploy* branch.

Checking out onto the other branch doesn't help because all the source files are dumped together with the `public` folder; sort of duplicating the *source* branch.

I'm looking for solutions of how to go about it.

**Note**

1. I'm not worried about the git history between the *source* and *deploy branches* diverging.

Comment: It's not a good idea to check generated files into your repository, since they tend to bloat your repository enormously.  You'd be better off using a different tool, such as Capistrano, to deploy rather than checking artifacts into your repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands should suffice:

```
git checkout deploy
git rm -rf .
mv --force public/* .
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
```